# sed - extract word beetwen two words in a single row without space

Tags: unix, sed

I need to extract one word beetwen two words in a single row without space.

For Example, i have this file web.xml :

```
<connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://sql2012:1433/AAA_1</connection-url>
<connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://sql2012:1433/BBB_1</connection-url>
<connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://sql2012:1433/CCC_2</connection-url>
```

I need extract `AAA_1` , `BBB_1` and `CCC_2`, because they stay in the middle of `1433/` and `</connection-url>`

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: if you parse xml with regex (like sed/awk/grep ...) you should have known the risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's~.*1433/\([^<]*\)</connection-url>.*~\1~' file
AAA_1
BBB_1
CCC_2
```

Through grep,

```
$ grep -oP '1433\/\K[^><]*' file
AAA_1
BBB_1
CCC_2
```

Comment: what is \K in grep. (I know -oP is catching pattern in perl re) btw I've voted upstairs

Comment: `\K` discards the previously matched chars from printing. In our case , the previously matched `1433/` would be discarded.